# Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC en Netbeans

Tags: java, base-de-datos, netbeans, sqlite

Estoy aprendiendo poco a poco y ahora quiero usar bases de datos.
Usando Netbeans 11.1 intento establecer una conexión con una tabla en SQLite, para ello hago lo siguiente

Tengo agregado en Services/Databases el driver de SQLite y he creado una conexión con mi base de datos que, al probarla, funciona sin problemas.

[image: Conexión funcionando...]

En mi código importo las siguientes interfaces:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
```

Creo las variables en mi clase para establecer los parámetros:

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
```

Y en el ActionPerformed del botón *conectar* tengo este código:

```
    private void btnConectarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // Se ha pulsado el botón CONECTAR

        // Establece la base de datos
        String BasedeDatos = "jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Arturo\\Dropbox\\Ubicaciones\\lista.db";
        // Intenta la conexión
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC").newInstance(); // <--- Aquí se detiene y salta el error

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(BasedeDatos);
            // Hay conexión
            if( conn == null ) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No se ha podido conectar","Conexión",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Conectado a la base de datos","Conexión",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }            
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Aunque intento verificar si se ha producido la conexión, en realidad nunca llega a entrar al **if**, se detiene la ejecución y me devuelve el error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
```

He leido en google que debería colocar el jar de sqlite en el classpath, pero a pesar de hacerlo, no consigo avanzar.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: agrega captura de tu proyecto en la parte que dice `libraries` para ver si realmente lo aregaste al classpath desde el IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he encontrado la solución.

La opción no era modificar el classpath.
Hay que agregar en la sección de dependencias una nueva, buscar sqlite e importar la versión con la que quieres trabajar. Netbeans la descarga y la agrega al proyecto.

et voilà!! Ya está funcionando.

Gracias

Comment: Al agregar una dependencia estás configurando que se agregue al classpath cuando corras tu aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberías poner

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.Driver");
```

es decir, que la clase es Driver, no JDBC.

Comment: Depende la versión, si sabes la versión en que funciona esto deberías de agregarlo. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hice en el netbeans IDE 17 y como base de datos SQLite, me tomó un tiempo averiguar bien como agregar correctamente el archivo, pero básicamente esta será una  explicación con manzanitas en base a la respuesta dada por "ARTURO":

En la ventana de Proyectos, buscas la carpeta **Dependencies(Dependencias)**, das Click Derecho y eliges la opcion **Add Dependency (Agregar Dependencia)**

[image: Imagen 1]

Rellenas los campos:

Group ID: Ponle un nombre distintivo, en mi caso yo puse el nombre del proyecto y lo terminé con ".libraryteste", para no confundirme, aunque puse una "e" demás, pero en realidad puedes ponerle cualquier cosa.

Artifact ID: Este es el nombre con el que lo vas a visualizar en la ventana de proyectos.

Version: No necesita un número específico, por último puedes poner 1.0.0 como yo, pero lo mas recomendable es que pongas la versión que pertenece el archivo que vas a subir a esta dependencia.

Scope: Dejala en **compile**, tal y como estaba desde un inicio o por defecto.

Los demás espacios, pueden quedar en blanco.

[image: Imagen 2]

[image: Imagen 3]

NOTA IMPORTANTE: Yo solo agregué 1 archivo, no sé si puedan subirse más en la misma dependencia o habrá que crear otra para subir un archivo nuevo.

Una vez que ya creaste la **Dependency (Dependencia)**, le das Click Derecho a esa nueva **Dependency(Dependencia)** y seleccionas la opción **Manually install artifact**, después clikeas la opción **Browse...**, se va a abrir la ventana para que busques tu archivo, en mi caso era el archivo **sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar**, el cual está en la misma carpeta en la que esta mi base de datos de SQLite y le das click al botón **Select** y finalmente clikeas el botón **Install locally**.

[image: Imagen 4]

[image: Imagen 5]

[image: Imagen 6]

[image: Imagen 7]

Con eso ya estará instalado.